# How to call a cell value on another sheet into tables on different sheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would appreciate any help for my case. So in sheet 1 called WIP, consist of item descriptions (C1) and quantity to be build (D1). The item description would be item name such as STD B, SGC B etc. On sheet 2 called SCH, consist of several tables in which each tables represent machine 1, machine 2 and so on. Machine 1 only able to build specific type such as STD B. Various types of STD B are on sheet 1. So would like to make the data on sheet 1 auto-populate the tables on sheet 2 based on item desc followed by the quantity. Reminder that data on sheet 1 always changing everyday. I was only able to pull the data based on it cell number, however what I need is the cell text value since all data in sheet 1 is always changing everyday. I tried Vlookup, indirect and even adding button using vb but couldn’t get the outcome that I want. Please help for any menthod or possible formula for this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [I downvoted because no attempt was made.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) Can you at least provide screenshots with current data and desirable outcome?

Comment: Well the only thing that I was able to do is using VB in excel by command button. I use Sheets (“WIP”).Range(“C57:D57).Copy Destination:=Sheets(SCH).Range(C13).. This only for cell value reference. If the value on C57 changed, the data will be changed too. I need the value reference not cell reference.

Comment: I couldn’t post a picture because it needs reputation to upload a pic

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague but I think you probably need to use the `VLOOKUP()` function. This function looks up a value in the first column of a range of cells and, if it finds the value, moves across a set number of columns and returns the value in that column. If it doesn't find a match, it returns an error (#NA from memory but may be something else).

So, on Sheet1, you many have:

```
    A     B     C    etc.
1   w
2   x
3   y
4   z
etc.
```

On Sheet2 you have the data you want to 'put into' Sheet1

```
    A     B     C    etc.
1   g   3.6
2   x   2.7
3   p   5.2
4   z   8.9
etc
```

You could use a `VLOOKUP()` function in the cells in Sheet1. You provide the function with a value to lookup, a range of cells and the column number from which to extract the data.

```
    A                                        B     C    etc.
1   w    =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)
2   x    =VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)
3   y    =VLOOKUP(C1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)
4   z    =VLOOKUP(D1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)
etc.
```

Which would give you:

```
    A      B     C    etc.
1   w    #NA
2   x    2.7
3   y    #NA
4   z    8.9
etc.
```

Basically, the function in B1 would look up the value 'w' in the first column of the range of cells provided (`Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4` - the $ signs make it an absolute reference) and return the value in column 2.

Search for `VLOOKUP` online to find what each parameter does but basically:

- 1st parameter = what you want to look up in the first column of the
  range of cells
- 2nd parameter = the range of cells from which you want
  to extract data
- 3rd parameter = the column number in the cell range
  that contains the data you want to extract
- 4th parameter = when set
  to FALSE, it will find an exact match. I always set this to FALSE but there may be occasions where you need to set it to TRUE.

Comment: Hi. Thanks mate for the respond. I do realize that I couldn’t explain the problem well due to some limitations. So in sheet 1 called WIP, consist of item descriptions (C1) and quantity to be build (D1). On sheet 2 called SCH, consist of several tables in which each tables represent machine 1, machine 2 and so on. Machine 1 only able to build specific type such as STD B.  Various types of STD B are on sheet 1. So  would like to make the data on sheet 1 auto-populate the tables on sheet 2 based on item desc. Reminder that data on sheet 1 always changing everyday.

Comment: You say, "Various types of STD B are on sheet 1." So do you want all the STD B types on sheet 1 to populate the Machine 1 table on sheet 2? Or do you want all the STD B types to be summarised in some way (e.g. average) and the summarised data to populate sheet 2?